# Base64 encode a string in Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

How do I base64 encode a string in cloud code? The value is for a HTTP Basic Auth.

I have tried the following two approaches and I had no success.

```
var string = 'AQXTTPmj-boT_yDEPQXg9ezIOIM7O:EMx6RLr8jF3S6YYo-X4bZ';
var buffer1 = new Buffer(string, 'base64');
var b3 = buffer1.toString('base64');
console.log(b3);
```

---

```
var string = 'AQXTTPmj-boT_yDEPQXg9ezIOIM7O:EMx6RLr8jF3S6YYo-X4bZ';
var encodeString = Base64.encode(string);
console.log(encodeString);
```

Comment: What problems did you have? Did you require buffer? Show more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send your string to the Buffer constructor and use `toString` method to convert it to `base64` like this:

```
var string = 'AQXTTPmj-boT_yDEPQXg9ezIOIM7O:EMx6RLr8jF3S6YYo-X4bZ';
var buffer1 = new Buffer(string);
var b3 = buffer1.toString('base64');
console.log(b3);
```

Also make sure you put `var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;` on top of your main.js file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I'm still getting an error that says "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined at main.js:89:20"...Line 89 is var buffer1 = new Buffer(string);

Comment: This is because you forgot to put `var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;` on top of your main.js file :) I updated the answer.